# Python call to AWS lambda - security token in the request is invalid

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda

The attempt to call an AWS lambda function from Python on windows fails.

I have reset my credentials to new AWS keys. No good.
I have added AWSLambdaFullAccess to my user ID and group. No workee.

```py
import boto3,json

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id="YesSireee",
    aws_secret_access_key="MySuperDuperSecretAccessKey",
)
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name="us-east-2")
test_event = dict(key1="testme") 
try: 
    response = lambda_client.invoke(
  FunctionName='arn_copied_from_console',
  InvocationType='Event',
  LogType='None',
  Payload=json.dumps(test_event),
  )
except Exception as e: print(e)
print(response); # should be None.
```

The error is:

```
An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the Invoke operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Comment: You are creating your own session but then creating the client using a default one. Shouldn’t that be `session.client(...`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild guess but is the time on your test system correct (for example using NTP)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

`lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name="us-east-2")`

It should be `session.client` instead of `boto3.client`. If you use `boto3.client`, it will search for credentials in the environment variables, credential file, IMDS etc, disregarding the session you created.

To use the credentials supplied in the code, use the `session.client`.

A better way to address this problem is to remove your credentials from your code, and populate them in the `~/.aws/credentials` file, or in your environment variables, and then continue using `boto3.client` without creating sessions with hard-coded credentials.

Hope that helps :)